What is this component: TEGdE1
Personal camera USB device stops charging, starts overheating after i plugged in fast-charge USB-c. I cut off battery wires because it shows red light while unresponsive and found burnt component.
What is this 5-pin component?




Please attach the image here, not a link to it. Also while markings are clear, can you take a second picture with a little bit more circutry around it, to see what the component might do in a circuit. Often, replacing a burned component will just burn again, unless a fault downstream is fixed first. It is likely that replacing this will not fix the device.

It's understandable that you can't get a good picture given that your camera is broken, but we need one anyway. One picture where the component print is clearly visible and another somewhat zoomed out of the surrounding components and traces. Also please keep in mind that "broken component" is always just a symptom, not the error cause.

I added more images and little bit more description. Thanks

The surrounding components let me think, it is a kind of load switch.

It's a TMI TMI6050-33 3.3V LDO.


(Source: lcsc.com)

Thank you so much i'll try to see if it works.
